# Change text color of dialog option items

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, android-alertdialog

I have this dialog in which the options appear with black text, and I would like to make it white

```
@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
private fun showPageSelectionDialog() {
    val options = arrayOf("A4", "A5") // User options

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle)
    builder.setTitle("Select PDF size")
    .setItems(options) { _, which ->
        val selectedPageSize = if (which == 1) PageSize.A5 else PageSize.A4
        pdf(name.text.toString().trim(), selectedPageSize)
    }
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    builder.create().show()
}
```

Since I use more dialogs in my app I created a custom style:

```
<!-- DIALOGUE -->
    <style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Also previously used:

```
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
```

And it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jorgesys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/jorgesys) answered in this question: [Cambiar color y propiedades de texto en un AlertDialog](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44504/cambiar-color-y-propiedades-de-texto-en-un-alertdialog/44505#44505), what solved the problem for me was adding this line to my options variable:

```
val options = arrayOf(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>A4</font>"),
                        Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>A5</font>"))
```

Although it is an obsolete method, it is the only one I have found that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle));
```

to  theme your Dialog. If you want to change the Button Colors use the following styling:

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
<item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item></style>
```

For the positive button:

```
<style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
<item name="android:textColor">#f00</item></style>
```

And for the negative button:

```
<style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
<item name="android:textColor">#00f</item></style>
```

Comment: but it is not for positive or negative buttons, but options (for example the title: "what color do you want?" and the options are A, B, C)

Comment: It seems you have implemented a custom Dialog have you? Then we would need the code you wrote, that displays the dialog and fills the list

Comment: The two codes are already there, the first is the dialogue and the second is the style

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
```

to your style

Comment: I already had that line previously and it didn't work

Comment: @HugoJiménez you should state that in your question post then.